# How to verify multiple actions in NServiceBus Handler

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nservicebus

I have a handler that needs to send a local message on every instance of an entity retrieved from a repository. The callback passed to `NServiceBus.Testing.Handler<>::ExpectSendLocal()` only gets invoked on the first invocation of `IBus::SendLocal()` in my handler. I've tried chaining a second `Handler<>::ExpectSendLocal()` but its callback is only invoked on the first one too. Here's an example handler:

```
public FooHandler : IHandleMessages<IFoo>
{
    public void Handle(IFoo message)
    {
        var bars = new [] {new Bar {Zap = "Zap1"}, new Bar {Zap = "Zap2"}};
        foreach (var bar in bars)
        {
          this.Bus().SendLocal<IBarProcessed>(barMsg => {
            barMsg.Zap = bar.Zap;
          });
          bar.IsProcessed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an example unit test that increments a count for `IBus::SendLocal()` expectations:

```
public void When_IFoo_message_received()
{
  int actualCount = 0;
  new NServiceBus.Testing.Handler<FooHandler>()
            .ExpectSendLocal<IBarProcessed>(completed => actualCount++)
            .OnMessage<IFoo>();
  Assert.AreEqual(2, actualCount); // fails because actualCount is one
}
```

Here's an example unit test that chains `NServiceBus.Testing.Handler<FooHandler>.ExpectSendLocal()` and checks for 2 different values from 2 messages:

```
public void When_IFoo_message_received()
{
  new NServiceBus.Testing.Handler<FooHandler>()
            .ExpectSendLocal<IBarProcessed>(completed => {
              Assert.AreEqual("Zap1", completed.Zap);
            })
            .ExpectSendLocal<IBarProcessed>(completed => {
              Assert.AreEqual("Zap2", completed.Zap); // fails because it's the value from the first one e.g. "Zap1"
            })
            .OnMessage<IFoo>();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug, would you mind raising a github issue for this?